# TV with relevant information

Tags: windows, facebook

I've got a 32" LG Smart TV and I was wondering if there exists some software for either the TV or something I can run on a computer and then connect the computer to the TV for displaying daily information.

If you've seen the Iron Man movies, I've seen that when she wakes up in the first film, all sorts of information is availible.

I want it to be a live feed of:

- Weather
- Time
- Facebook
- perhaps Instagram feed + newspaper news.

Does it exist something like this I can download and run?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! Though your description holds several criteria required to recommend matching software, it suffers some formatting issues to make them clearly stand out. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. This will significantly improve your chances of good answers!

Comment: Thanks;) I'll take a look and see what I can do;)

Comment: One thing to consider would be media center software, which could stream all this to your TV. Take e.g. a look at [MythTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythTV); not that exactly this product would be a solution for you, but it might give you some ideas of what's possible, when updating your question.

Comment: If you're hooking it up to a computer, you might look into [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/). Not necessarily for beginners, though.

Comment: As you added both tags, [tag:windows-7] and [tag:windows-8], a solution must run on both versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/).

To quote the little blurb on their site:

> Rainmeter displays customizable skins, like memory and battery power, RSS feeds and weather forecasts, right on your desktop. Many skins are even functional: they can record your notes and to-do lists, launch your favorite applications, and control your media player - all in a clean, unobtrusive interface that you can rearrange and customize to your liking. Rainmeter is at once an application and a toolkit. You are only limited by your imagination and creativity.

Rainmter makes it easy to keep an eye on information such as:

- memory
- battery power
- online data streams
- email
- RSS feeds
- weather forecasts.

Rainmeter is free of charge and licensed under [GNU GPL v2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0)

For a good place to start on designing your own apps, I would suggest reading the [Rainmeter manual](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual)

Otherwise I would recommend visiting the [Discover](http://rainmeter.net/discover) page to find a theme from one of the available sites such as [customize.org](http://customize.org/rainmeter/skins) or [Deviant Art](http://rainmeter.deviantart.com/gallery/).

---

A few example themes (click for source/download):

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>compilation source and more themes: http://windows7themes.net/8-free-windows-7-rainmeter-themes.html</sub>

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks! Btw; I've got an extra computer with just 1GB of ram - it would run on that, wouldn't it? So that I can have my main pc free. The 1gig pc ain't going to be used for anything else